# Symfony 2 Input Date, displaying only dates before today

Tags: php, symfony

this is what momently im using to create an input field:

```
$builder->add('foundingdate', 'date')... // more fields
```

it is displaying dates in the future like this:

```
10.18.13
10.19.13
10.20.13
...
..
10.20.15
..
.
```

Is there a simple way to display just days before today ?

**Example**:

today is 10.17.13 so the input just should display

```
10.16.13
10.15.13
10.14.13
...
..
.
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code snippet, you use the default widget, so you have 3 lists, one for year, one for month and one for day? If you [restrict values for months or days](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#years), you will make it impossible to select some days. It will work only for year. For example, on 17th october, if you remove the days after 17, the user will not be able to select 25th september. I suggest you to use [validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) to check that the submitted date is in the past.

Edit: you can use the new attribute `max=""` with `<input type="date" />` (see [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp)). It works on Chrome but not on Firefox, try this

```php
$builder->add('foundingdate', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'attr' => array(
        'max' => date('Y-m-d')
    )
));
```

Comment: of course, i'll validate this in the backend, but in eyes of usabillity it wouldn't make sense to let pick the user a release date that is in the past.